# Tree Data Structure: I cannnot get any data output

Tags: visual-c++

Whenever I run the code and enter a file, I do not seem to get any output.

What I was trying to get the program to do was take int input from a file (ignoring any other form of data, and only accepting numbers 0-99 inclusive); then using the first number as the top of the tree structure, sort the data with the smaller integers going to the left and larger integers go to the right.

The output was to be formatted where it prints the numbers in order lowest to highest, and also prints what level of the tree they were on (the top would be 0 then level below would be 1, below 1 would be 2 and so on).

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I have tried running a few loops in the printData, and readAndInsert functions, but it has not given me any ideas as to what is going wrong.

```
// include libraries needed
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

// create the tree node
struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *Left;
    struct node *Right;
};

// declare functions that will be used and defined later
void printData(struct node *);
void deleteData(struct node *);
struct node *newNode(int);
struct node *insert(struct node *&, int);
string takeFileName();
int readAndInsert(string, struct node *&);

int main()
{
    // create a node to be used in the program
    struct node *Root;
    Root = new node;

    // make sure the node was created
    if (Root == NULL)
    {
        cout << endl << "Fatal error, coul dnot create newRoot node. " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    // set Root equal to NULL for the insert function
    Root = NULL;

    // call the apropriate functions
    readAndInsert(takeFileName(), Root);
    printData(Root);
    deleteData(Root);

    // pause the console to see any error output
    system("pause");

    // successful run
    return 0;
}

// function to print the data to a file
void printData(struct node *root)
{
    // create an out stream and text file
    ofstream out;
    out.open("tree.txt");

    // Check to see that the file opened and output error message.
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        cout << "There was a problem opening the file. " << endl;
        cout << "Please try again. " << endl;
    }

    // optional edit to print
    out << "Data" << "\t" << "Level" << endl;

    // create a node to be used in the program
    struct node *Root;
    Root = new node;

    // make sure the node was created
    if (Root == NULL)
    {
        cout << endl << "Fatal error, coul dnot create newRoot node. " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    // set Root equal to NULL for the insert function
    Root = root;

    if (Root != NULL)
    {
        // print and rotate to a different node
        printData(root-> Left);
        out << root->number << endl;
        printData(root-> Right);
    }

    // close the out stream file 
    out.close();
}

// function to delete the data
void deleteData(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        deleteData(root->Left);
        deleteData(root->Right);
        delete(root);
    }
}

struct node *newNode(int data)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->number = data;
    temp->Left = NULL;
    temp->Right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// function to insert data
struct node *insert(struct node *&root, int data)
{
    // create a node to be used in the program
    struct node *Root;
    Root = new node;

    // make sure the node was created
    if (Root == NULL)
    {
        cout << endl << "Fatal error, coul dnot create newRoot node. " << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    // set Root equal to NULL for the insert function
    Root = root;

    if (Root == NULL) 
        return newNode(data);

    if (data < Root->number)
        Root->Left = insert(Root->Left, data);

    else if (data > Root->number)
        Root->Right = insert(Root->Right, data);

    return Root;
}

// This function will take input from the user to be used as the fileName then return the name so 
// it can be used in other functions.
string takeFileName()
{
    // Create a fileName variable that can hole the file name to be entered.
    string fileName;

    // Output instructions to the user.
    cout << "Please enter a file name that you would like to read from (ex. InFile.txt): " << endl;

    // Take input for the fileName
    cin >> fileName;

    // Return the fileName so that it can pass to another function
    return fileName;
}

// read from the file and insert the numbers into the tree
int readAndInsert(string fileName, struct node *&root)
{
    // Start reading in from whatever file name was input.
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(fileName);

    // Check to see that the file opened and output error message.
    if (!readFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "The fileName was not correct or there was a problem opening the file. " << endl;
        cout << "Please try again. " << endl;

        return (1); // unsuccessful run
    }

    // Run a loop to end of file and put the numbers into the tree
    while (true)
    {
        // Create a variable x to hold the current value read from the file.
        int x;

        // Take a number from the file.
        readFile >> x;

        // Set if statement to ignore any bad non-numeric data.
        if (readFile.fail())
        {
            // Clear the bad entry, and then ignore it so as to avoid an infinite loop of bad data.
            readFile.clear();
            readFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

            // Take in the next line of the file.
            readFile >> x;
        }

        // Break the loop at the end of the file.
        if (readFile.eof())
        {
            break;
        }

        // create a node to be used in the program
        struct node *Root;
        Root = new node;

        // make sure the node was created
        if (Root == NULL)
        {
            cout << endl << "Fatal error, coul dnot create newRoot node. " << endl;
            system("pause");
        }

        // set Root equal to NULL for the insert function
        Root = root;

        // Set if statement to sort only numbers that are 0-99.
        if (x >= 0 && x <= 99)
        {
            if (Root == NULL)
            {
                Root = insert(Root, x);
            }

            else if (Root != NULL)
            {
                // insert and sort them into the tree
                insert(Root, x);
            }
        }
    }

    // Close the readFile;
    readFile.close();

    return (0); // successful run
}
```

With the code above, I was looking to get an output of the numbers input into the tree in order of least to greatest (or lowest to highest), but nothing was output when the file was entered.

Comment: You need to narrow down where the issue is. Is the file being loaded? Is the list created properly? Etc. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have tried, but not been able to narrow down to where exactly it is going wrong. It does take the file in without a problem, and if I enter something like a wrong file name it displays the error to the console.

Comment: I think it might be something with my nodes and I'm losing my place before I print out the tree. (more specifically is I fill the tree, then I'm calling the last node to print so there is nothing after that so it then prints nothing, or I'm filling a different node that does not get returned to the main function.) I know I have had problems with this before, but since the code does not trigger any error messages in visual studio, I have no clue.

Comment: You pass a reference to the root node, but never use it. There's no need for a temp node - just use the root. Here's an example. I'm not typing an answer because I am leaving for the day: https://ideone.com/nZ4Iki